# Google Maps infowindow close button is hidden

Tags: google-maps

I used Google Maps in my website with multiple markers and multiple infowindows. Somehow the the close buttons (the little x) stays hidden inside the infowindow, but works if clicked at the position where it should be displayed. How to fix this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

fixed it, apparently bootstrap.css was conflicting with the images and had to use these few extra lines of css

```
<style type="text/css">
/** FIX for Bootstrap and Google Maps Info window styes problem **/
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {
max-width: none;
}
</style>
```

anyone facing the same problem may solve your issue using this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
max-width: none !important;
```

this will help you with any other rule

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your custom css you may have also to add **max-height: none**.

```
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
```