# Javascript gmaps api Close button not showing

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, infowindow, ionic3

My question is similar to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708324/google-maps-infowindow-close-button-is-hidden)

The problem is my close Button on Infowindow ist not dislayed, but the button works.
I tried many things, maybe you can help with a little hint or solution :)

Thank you very much in advance!

Home.ts

```
setProductMarker(product :any, productLocation :any){

var productMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(JSON.parse(productLocation).latitude, JSON.parse(productLocation).longitude),
  map: this.map,
  title: "Product"
})


var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "test"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', () => {
  //now my elements are ready for dom manipulation
  var clickableItem = document.getElementById('clickableItem');
  clickableItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.goToProductPage(product);
  });
});


productMarker.addListener('click', event => {
  if( this.prev_infowindow ) {
       this.prev_infowindow.close();
    }

    this.prev_infowindow = infoWindow;
infoWindow.open(this.map, productMarker);

});
```

}

home.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

home.css

```
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {
    max-width: none;
 }
```

Here is a screenshot of one infoWindow : 
[image]

Weird is when I put my app on a ftp server, the close button is there ..[image]